# React JS Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time use `React JS`, I stuck with this error,

I am trying to learn react router from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iAG6h9ff5s)
also watched it multiple times, but I still can't find and solve the problem:

**package.json**

```
{
      "name": "cobareact",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "app pertama react",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "history": "^1.17.0",
        "react": "^15.5.4",
        "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
        "react-router": "^4.1.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack": "^2.5.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^2.5.1"
      }
    }
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from './App.jsx';
import About from './About.js';
import Add from './Add.js';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='' component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={About}></IndexRoute>
            <Route path='about' component={About}></Route>
            <Route path='add' component={Add}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ButtonAdd from './ButtonAdd';
import ButtonAbout from './ButtonAbout';
import Contacts from './Contacts';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component{
   render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <div>
               {this.props.children}
               <div><Link to="add"><ButtonAdd /></Link><Link to="about"><ButtonAbout /></Link></div>
               <h1>Contact Book</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
               <Contacts lists={CONTACTS} />
            </div>
        </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

**error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`enter code here`
```

**warning**

Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash history has been replaced by `HashRouter` which has been moved to a new package

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Further details here:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md

Comment: thank its work, when i click the button
it doesn't show anything, 
i use {this.props.children} same as in the video but
when i console.log(this.props) i can't find children object
i'm sorry this is my first time

Answer (score 1):

While writing in **React Router v4** you have to take care of following facts:

1. `hashHistory` is no more supported. If you want to achieve the same 
   behaviour you have to use [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) instead.
2. `<IndexRoute>` is replaced by a regular `<Route>`. Add `exact` prop to routes.
3. `Nested Routes` are no more supported. You have to put nested routes 
   inside child components.

   ```
   import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

   ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
       <Route path='' component={App}/>
    </HashRouter>, 
   document.getElementById('app'));
   ```

Comment: thank its work, when i click the button
it doesn't show anything, 
i use {this.props.children} same as in the video but
when i console.log(this.props) i can't find children object
i'm sorry this is my first time

Answer (score 0):

you are watching a video from februari 2016, the api of react-router has totally changed, it has been rewritten totally. I saw they use react router 1x in the video. You are using react router 4. i didnt dive into react router 4 yet, but they this.props.children should be seen as this for example

```
import Component from './Component.js';
import OtherComponent from './OtherComponent';

<Component>
  <OtherComponent />
</Component>
```

within the Component.js file other OtherComponent.js
wil be available at this.props.children

so in ur example, ur code expects some props to be available on the props (.children), that are i assume are not passed on by react router 4.

further info: 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api or downgrate to the version of react router they use within the video,

but they also provide some tutorials for example at egghead into react-router v4

Comment: i am sorry, i think if i use new version of react it will no issue when i try tutorial who using older version
thanks for your answer,

Comment: no , not a new version of react.. a new version of REACT-ROUTER, makes a big difference, in the tutorial u are following:)